# How to redraw polygon using DrawingManager from "react-google-maps"

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

Trying to show predefined coordinates drawn in 'react-google-maps' using DrawingManager

Tried to use 'paths' from 'polygonOptions' to achieve it but it didn't
'
The paths property is ignored, and the map property of a new polygon is always set to the DrawingManager's map
'
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/drawing#DrawingManagerOptions.polygonOptions

I found a solution using vanilla js
http://jsfiddle.net/FUUxz/

I need a solution using 'react-google-maps'

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
import React from "react";
import { compose, withProps } from "recompose";
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap } from "react-google-maps";
import { GOOGLE_MAP_KEY } from "../../../config/general";

const coords = [
  [
    { lat: 51.509674, lng: -0.193036 },
    { lat: 51.50947, lng: -0.194151 },
    { lat: 51.509116, lng: -0.194034 },
    { lat: 51.509043, lng: -0.19451 },
    { lat: 51.508987, lng: -0.194893 },
    { lat: 51.508931, lng: -0.195204 },
    { lat: 51.508837, lng: -0.195909 },
    { lat: 51.508898, lng: -0.195922 },
    { lat: 51.508636, lng: -0.19703 },
    { lat: 51.508572, lng: -0.197381 },
    { lat: 51.508483, lng: -0.197726 },
    { lat: 51.508389, lng: -0.198136 },
    { lat: 51.508559, lng: -0.198215 },
    { lat: 51.508449, lng: -0.198656 },
    { lat: 51.508334, lng: -0.19927 },
    { lat: 51.508355, lng: -0.19937 },
    { lat: 51.508404, lng: -0.199497 },
    { lat: 51.508372, lng: -0.200011 },
    { lat: 51.508308, lng: -0.200201 },
    { lat: 51.50819, lng: -0.20015 },
    { lat: 51.508158, lng: -0.200309 },
    { lat: 51.507973, lng: -0.200178 },
    { lat: 51.508009, lng: -0.199983 },
    { lat: 51.507734, lng: -0.199859 },
    { lat: 51.507595, lng: -0.200528 },
    { lat: 51.507496, lng: -0.20047 },
    { lat: 51.5074, lng: -0.200796 },
    { lat: 51.507916, lng: -0.201185 },
    { lat: 51.507734, lng: -0.20186 },
    { lat: 51.507004, lng: -0.201298 },
    { lat: 51.50681, lng: -0.202022 },
    { lat: 51.507523, lng: -0.202634 },
    { lat: 51.507358, lng: -0.203272 },
    { lat: 51.507264, lng: -0.203558 },
    { lat: 51.506737, lng: -0.203296 },
    { lat: 51.505841, lng: -0.202894 },
    { lat: 51.50503, lng: -0.202407 },
    { lat: 51.504359, lng: -0.202 },
    { lat: 51.503979, lng: -0.203986 },
    { lat: 51.505132, lng: -0.204652 },
    { lat: 51.504314, lng: -0.207929 },
    { lat: 51.50485, lng: -0.208263 },
    { lat: 51.504698, lng: -0.208794 },
    { lat: 51.50548, lng: -0.209299 },
    { lat: 51.505231, lng: -0.210223 },
    { lat: 51.505093, lng: -0.21072 },
    { lat: 51.505384, lng: -0.211053 },
    { lat: 51.505344, lng: -0.211453 },
    { lat: 51.505514, lng: -0.211823 },
    { lat: 51.505348, lng: -0.211854 },
    { lat: 51.505309, lng: -0.211988 },
    { lat: 51.505195, lng: -0.212567 },
    { lat: 51.504979, lng: -0.213457 },
    { lat: 51.504719, lng: -0.213341 },
    { lat: 51.50446, lng: -0.21386 },
    { lat: 51.50409, lng: -0.214612 },
    { lat: 51.503675, lng: -0.21538 },
    { lat: 51.503819, lng: -0.215575 },
    { lat: 51.503955, lng: -0.215803 },
    { lat: 51.504157, lng: -0.216115 },
    { lat: 51.504697, lng: -0.216664 },
    { lat: 51.505006, lng: -0.216933 },
    { lat: 51.505154, lng: -0.217028 },
    { lat: 51.506635, lng: -0.218002 },
    { lat: 51.507697, lng: -0.218438 },
    { lat: 51.509346, lng: -0.219019 },
    { lat: 51.510592, lng: -0.219563 },
    { lat: 51.510783, lng: -0.218558 },
    { lat: 51.510973, lng: -0.218644 },
    { lat: 51.51139, lng: -0.217159 },
    { lat: 51.511867, lng: -0.217508 },
    { lat: 51.512312, lng: -0.217786 },
    { lat: 51.513191, lng: -0.217742 },
    { lat: 51.513566, lng: -0.217693 },
    { lat: 51.513786, lng: -0.217376 },
    { lat: 51.514472, lng: -0.216459 },
    { lat: 51.514837, lng: -0.215982 },
    { lat: 51.514681, lng: -0.214373 },
    { lat: 51.514809, lng: -0.214046 },
    { lat: 51.51498, lng: -0.214358 },
    { lat: 51.515125, lng: -0.21464 },
    { lat: 51.515283, lng: -0.214953 },
    { lat: 51.515408, lng: -0.215209 },
    { lat: 51.51574, lng: -0.214768 },
    { lat: 51.51602, lng: -0.214328 },
    { lat: 51.51621, lng: -0.214002 },
    { lat: 51.516432, lng: -0.213602 },
    { lat: 51.516688, lng: -0.21307 },
    { lat: 51.516888, lng: -0.212534 },
    { lat: 51.516994, lng: -0.212201 },
    { lat: 51.517134, lng: -0.211736 },
    { lat: 51.517035, lng: -0.211667 },
    { lat: 51.517105, lng: -0.211376 },
    { lat: 51.516988, lng: -0.211305 },
    { lat: 51.517082, lng: -0.210853 },
    { lat: 51.517141, lng: -0.210545 },
    { lat: 51.516732, lng: -0.210296 },
    { lat: 51.516876, lng: -0.209659 },
    { lat: 51.517014, lng: -0.209062 },
    { lat: 51.517877, lng: -0.209587 },
    { lat: 51.518054, lng: -0.208841 },
    { lat: 51.518286, lng: -0.208129 },
    { lat: 51.518492, lng: -0.20758 },
    { lat: 51.518784, lng: -0.207045 },
    { lat: 51.519139, lng: -0.206478 },
    { lat: 51.519616, lng: -0.205846 },
    { lat: 51.520117, lng: -0.205226 },
    { lat: 51.520539, lng: -0.204596 },
    { lat: 51.520834, lng: -0.204102 },
    { lat: 51.521147, lng: -0.203341 },
    { lat: 51.521347, lng: -0.202625 },
    { lat: 51.521484, lng: -0.202017 },
    { lat: 51.521577, lng: -0.201501 },
    { lat: 51.521621, lng: -0.201069 },
    { lat: 51.521142, lng: -0.200714 },
    { lat: 51.520706, lng: -0.200381 },
    { lat: 51.520257, lng: -0.200017 },
    { lat: 51.519936, lng: -0.199719 },
    { lat: 51.519321, lng: -0.19918 },
    { lat: 51.518564, lng: -0.198376 },
    { lat: 51.518482, lng: -0.198646 },
    { lat: 51.5182, lng: -0.198452 },
    { lat: 51.517723, lng: -0.198155 },
    { lat: 51.517866, lng: -0.198674 },
    { lat: 51.517713, lng: -0.199232 },
    { lat: 51.517543, lng: -0.199123 },
    { lat: 51.517442, lng: -0.199467 },
    { lat: 51.517221, lng: -0.199317 },
    { lat: 51.517042, lng: -0.200034 },
    { lat: 51.516869, lng: -0.199919 },
    { lat: 51.51666, lng: -0.199702 },
    { lat: 51.516671, lng: -0.19937 },
    { lat: 51.515998, lng: -0.199152 },
    { lat: 51.515835, lng: -0.199152 },
    { lat: 51.515473, lng: -0.19917 },
    { lat: 51.515328, lng: -0.199102 },
    { lat: 51.515319, lng: -0.198636 },
    { lat: 51.515311, lng: -0.198433 },
    { lat: 51.515027, lng: -0.198351 },
    { lat: 51.515126, lng: -0.197644 },
    { lat: 51.515567, lng: -0.197507 },
    { lat: 51.515579, lng: -0.197053 },
    { lat: 51.515289, lng: -0.196986 },
    { lat: 51.515302, lng: -0.196312 },
    { lat: 51.515353, lng: -0.195184 },
    { lat: 51.515069, lng: -0.195067 },
    { lat: 51.514918, lng: -0.195032 },
    { lat: 51.514796, lng: -0.195232 },
    { lat: 51.514608, lng: -0.195556 },
    { lat: 51.514356, lng: -0.195169 },
    { lat: 51.514108, lng: -0.195138 },
    { lat: 51.514091, lng: -0.195507 },
    { lat: 51.514209, lng: -0.195559 },
    { lat: 51.514158, lng: -0.196059 },
    { lat: 51.513977, lng: -0.195994 },
    { lat: 51.513696, lng: -0.196288 },
    { lat: 51.513425, lng: -0.196522 },
    { lat: 51.513344, lng: -0.196312 },
    { lat: 51.512859, lng: -0.196239 },
    { lat: 51.512816, lng: -0.196908 },
    { lat: 51.512375, lng: -0.197152 },
    { lat: 51.51223, lng: -0.197723 },
    { lat: 51.512025, lng: -0.197748 },
    { lat: 51.511752, lng: -0.197725 },
    { lat: 51.511592, lng: -0.197712 },
    { lat: 51.511545, lng: -0.197337 },
    { lat: 51.511096, lng: -0.197239 },
    { lat: 51.510389, lng: -0.197132 },
    { lat: 51.510039, lng: -0.197037 },
    { lat: 51.50966, lng: -0.196927 },
    { lat: 51.509219, lng: -0.19679 },
    { lat: 51.509273, lng: -0.196552 },
    { lat: 51.509351, lng: -0.196023 },
    { lat: 51.509481, lng: -0.196054 },
    { lat: 51.50954, lng: -0.19565 },
    { lat: 51.509627, lng: -0.19568 },
    { lat: 51.509741, lng: -0.194873 },
    { lat: 51.509626, lng: -0.194822 },
    { lat: 51.509774, lng: -0.193945 },
    { lat: 51.509903, lng: -0.193127 },
    { lat: 51.509771, lng: -0.193075 },
    { lat: 51.509674, lng: -0.193036 }
  ]
];

const {
  DrawingManager
} = require("react-google-maps/lib/components/drawing/DrawingManager");

const DrawingManagerWrapper = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${GOOGLE_MAP_KEY}&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places`,
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props => (
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={12}
    defaultCenter={new google.maps.LatLng(51.509865, -0.118092)}
  >
    <DrawingManager
      setMap={GoogleMap}
      overlaycomplete={props.onComplete}
      defaultOptions={{
        drawingControl: true,
        // drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        drawingControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
          drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON]
        },
        polygonOptions: {
          fillColor: "#199ee0",
          fillOpacity: 0.2,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          strokeColor: "#113460",
          clickable: true,
          editable: true,
          geodesic: false,
          visible: true,
          zIndex: 1,
          paths: coords
        }
      }}
    />
  </GoogleMap>
));

export default DrawingManagerWrapper;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw a polygon from predefined coordinates use `Polygon` component instead, like this:

```
 <Polygon
      path={triangleCoords}
      key={1}
      editable={true}
      options={{
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.35
      }}
    />
```

where

```
const triangleCoords = [
  { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19 },
  { lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118 },
  { lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757 },
  { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19 }
];
```

> **Note** set `editable` property to true to allow edit polygon via UI

`DrawingManager` component is only intended to draw polygons via UI since

> The `DrawingManager` class provides a graphical interface for users
>   to draw polygons, rectangles, polylines, circles, and markers on the
>   map

Here is an example on how to:

- draw (editable) polygon from provided coordinates
- display drawing control to edit/add polygons

**Example**

```
/* global google */
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Polygon
} from "react-google-maps";
import { DrawingManager } from "react-google-maps/lib/components/drawing/DrawingManager";

const triangleCoords = [
  { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19 },
  { lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118 },
  { lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757 },
  { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19 }
];

function Map(props) {
  const {zoom,center} = props;
  return (
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={zoom}
      defaultCenter={center}
    >
      <Polygon
        path={triangleCoords}
        key={1}
        editable={true}
        options={{
          strokeColor: "#FF0000",
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: "#FF0000",
          fillOpacity: 0.35
        }}
      />

      <DrawingManager
        defaultDrawingMode={google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON}
        defaultOptions={{
          drawingControl: true,
          drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON]
          },
          polygonOptions: {editable:true}
        }}
      />
    </GoogleMap>
  );
}

export default withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));
```

Comment: Super it's working but whenever I start redrawing again the Polygon disappear & the DrawingManager override it, is there a way to keep both components?

Comment: Bro it was my bad, the solution is working correctly there was an issue in the state

Comment: I am sorry for the basic questionIs - is this frontend or backend. When I try using it on the frontend I am getting `google` is not defined. If you look at the code where is the `google` coming from.  What does it mean `/* global google */` ? I know what `global` means but where is it coming from?